# Unit tests strategy : redundancy using Black-box

Tags: unit-testing, oop, black-box-testing

I'am having an issue designing black-box unit tests without redundancy.

Here is an example :

```
class A {
   Float function operationA(int: aNumber){
        if(aNumber > 0){
            return aNumber * 10 + 5.2;
        }
        else if (aNumber < 0) {
            return aNumber * 7 - 5.2;
        }
        else {
            return aNumber * 78 + 9.3;
        }
    }
}

class B {
    boolean status = true;

    Float function opearationB(int: theNumber){
        if(status == true){
            return a.operationA(aNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to correctly test A.operationA(), I would have to write at least three unit tests (`aNumber` = 0, `aNumber` > 0 and `aNumber` < 0).

Now let's say I want to test B.functionB, using black-box strategy, should I re-write the similar three unit tests (`theNumber`= 0, `theNumber`> 0 and `theNumber`< 0) ? In that case, I would have to create a lot of tests each time I use the method A.operationA ...

Comment: why is there a black box test requirement?

Comment: The tests for `class A` would be sufficient. `class A` is a dependency of class B. when testing B, class A could be mocked/faked so as to test only the additional functionality of B. No need to retest functionality what has already been covered.

Comment: @dm03514 Using black-box strategy in that case would allow the unit tests to fail when operationA is changed and returns a result that change the result of operationB. This could not be achieved by just checking that operationA has been called in operationB (white-box strategy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the black box constraint can be loosened you can remove all the duplication.  I really like Jay Fields definitions of solitary vs sociable unit tests, [explained here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html).

It should be trivial to test class `A` in isolation.  It has no side effects and no collaborators.  Ideally class B could also be tested in isolation (solitary) where it's collaborator's, class a, is stubbed out.  Not only does this let you exercise class `B` in isolation, it helps control cascading failures.  If class B is tested with the real life class A when class A changes it could cause a failure in class B.

At some point collaboration (sociable) should probably be checked, a couple ways may be:

- a single socialable test that calls b through its public interface and triggers the default case in class A
- Higher level tests that exercise a specific user story or external flow path, which triggers class B

Sorry didn't answer your direct question.